# Windows directory juction: no files are copied via network access

Tags: windows, file, directory, shared-directory, junction

I have a problem with file storage organization.
There is a network of Windows 7 and Windows XP computers. One of them is a file storage server.

Software packs are located on the storage server. Each software pack includes
1. `active` folder;
1. some folders for each program.

(see the structure example below)

**Active folder** is a structure of the actual program's versions, must allow to copy all the software in their actual versions avoiding file's duplicating via direct copying. Also fast switching of actual version is needed.

**Program folders** contain folders for each program's version.

I tried to solve the task via windows `directory junction`. I created the links via `Far Manager 3`, command `Alt+F6`, type `directory junction`.

## Desired structure example

```
+---active % 389 MB, desired package of actual software
|   +---notepad++ % directory junction
|   |   \---7.3.1
|   |           npp.7.3.1.Installer.exe
|   |           npp.7.3.1.Installer.x64.exe
|   |
|   +---octave % directory junction
|   |   \---4.2.1
|   |           octave-4.2.1-w32-installer.exe
|   |           octave-4.2.1-w64-installer.exe
|   |
|   \---texstudio % directory junction
|       \---2.12.4
|               texstudio-2.12.4-win-qt5.6.2.exe
|
+---notepad++
|   +---6.8.8
|   |       npp.6.8.8.Installer.exe
|   |
|   \---7.3.1 % actual version
|           npp.7.3.1.Installer.exe
|           npp.7.3.1.Installer.x64.exe
|
+---octave
|   +---4.2.0
|   |       octave-4.2.0-w32-installer.exe
|   |       octave-4.2.0-w64-installer.exe
|   |       octave-4.2.0-w64.zip
|   |
|   \---4.2.1 % actual version
|           octave-4.2.1-w32-installer.exe
|           octave-4.2.1-w64-installer.exe
|
\---texstudio
    +---2.11.0
    |       texstudio-2.11.0-win-qt5.5.1.exe
    |
    +---2.12.0
    |       texstudio-2.12.0-win-qt5.6.2.exe
    |
    +---2.12.2
    |       texstudio-2.12.2-win-qt5.6.2.exe
    |
    \---2.12.4 % actual version
            texstudio-2.12.4-win-qt5.6.2.exe
```

## Local usage

Local means I operate on the storage server's Windows GUI.
If to copy `active` folder to another server's folder observed result is the same as desired:

```
TEST_COPY
    \---active % 389 MB, all the files are copied
        +---notepad++
        |   \---7.3.1
        |           npp.7.3.1.Installer.exe
        |           npp.7.3.1.Installer.x64.exe
        |
        +---octave
        |   \---4.2.1
        |           octave-4.2.1-w32-installer.exe
        |           octave-4.2.1-w64-installer.exe
        |
        \---texstudio
            \---2.12.4
                    texstudio-2.12.4-win-qt5.6.2.exe
```

## Network file access

If to access to the storage server's `active` folder via network sharing and copy it the desired result does not happen.
Of course, `tree /A /F` command shows the same structure of the copied tree, but `active` is 0 MB size and child folders `notepad++`, `octave`, `texstudio` are also zero-sized and empty.

```
TEST_COPY
    \---active % 0 MB, no any files, only subfolders
        +---notepad++
        |   \---7.3.1
        |
        +---octave
        |   \---4.2.1
        |
        \---texstudio
            \---2.12.4
```

Only if try to copy directly directory junctions subfolders inside `active` folder (`7.3.1`, `4.2.1`, `2.12.4`) the content will be copied as desired. But every user wants to copy `active` folder, not its second level childs.

BTW. Sometimes when trying to copy an error occurred: file/folder already exists, and copy process was broken unexpectedly.

May be links are set up wrong or there are other methods to reach the desired result.

Comment: What are you using to copy? If Robocopy you need to specify a flag to copy directory junctions.

Comment: @Ben, I copy using Windows explorer (`active` folder Copy-Paste) or `Far Manager 3` (copy using `F5`). And I suppose that all users will use explorer or Far. I think most of all users will not recognize directory junction, they will see regular windows folder.

Comment: Does the directory junction use the full path (not a relative path)?

Comment: @Ben, yes, when directory junction is created via `Far Manager 3` `Alt+F6` command, it uses absolute path by default, e.g. `D:\StackOverflow\WinSym\active\notepad++` is path to create directory junction from `D:\StackOverflow\WinSym\notepad++\7.3.1`.